# Can server sided games (like Clash of Clans) be by-passed login?

Tags: server-side, google-play-games

There are many games which use login but are in client side... But, can the games like Clash of Clans, Clash Royale and others be by-passed the login sequence and open up with a random profile though it uses Google Play games for verification, there must be some method? (its not related to 'hacking' but quite to 'enthusiastic'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, until we have access to **Google Account** which can help in *by-passing* the login sequence (**'quite' close to it**) .. The other methods might fall under **other** catagory so I'd rather prevent myself falling into that!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the logic to handle an anonymous profile is on the back end server.  You can use an approach like [Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) on Android and iOS to identify the player.  Firebase Authentication also has the added advantage of being able to associate multiple authentication types to the same user, so if the game player decides to sign in with Google, or Facebook, for example, they won't lose anything they did as the anonymous user.